# SELECT2 STOPPED TO WORK

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the select2 component (Version: 3.4.8), but suddenly it stopped working. This is my code:

```
$('#acompanhantes').select2({
    formatNoMatches: 'Nenhum resultado encontrado',
    formatSearching: 'Buscando...',
    formatSelection: format,
    formatResult: format,
    multiple: true,
    ajax: {
            url: "query.php?acao=listar_nome_usuarios&exceto=<?=$_SESSION["usuario"]["id_colaborador"];?>",
            dataType: 'json',
            type: "POST",
            data: function (term) {
                return {
                    termo: term
                };
            },
            results: function (data) {
                return {results: data};
            }
        },
    });

    function format(item) { 
        return capitalize(item.text);
    }
```

Does anyone know how can I debug to know where it went wrong? I'm still getting a result, but when I type in the input, it does not search and also does not insert underline.

Comment: did you get some error in the console? I think that your url isn't well composed

Comment: No comma after the closing `ajax` bracket.

Answer (score 1):

You had JSON syntax wrong. Try now

```
$('#acompanhantes').select2({
    formatNoMatches: 'Nenhum resultado encontrado',
    formatSearching: 'Buscando...',
    formatSelection: format,
    formatResult: format,
    multiple: true,
    ajax: {
            url: 'query.php?acao=listar_nome_usuarios&exceto=<?=$_SESSION["usuario"]["id_colaborador"];?>',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: "POST",
            data: function (term) {
                return {
                    termo: term
                };
            },
            results: function (data) {
                return {results: data};
            }
        }
    });

    function format(item) { 
        return capitalize(item.text);
    }
```